# How to create Binding in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

use Visual Studio 2013, c#

Try to create on main page binding to current time - whant that each second time changed on page. (just try to understand binding a little bit better)

What was done:

1. Created special class with implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`

   ```
   using System.ComponentModel;
   //this class must be used for binding changed time on main page
   namespace Memo
   {
   //Implement INotifiyPropertyChanged 
   //interface to subscribe for property change notifications
   class DateTimeNow : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   private string _currentDateTimeNow;

   //simple prop
   public string CurrentDateTimeNow
   {
       get { return _currentDateTimeNow; }
       set
       {
           if (_currentDateTimeNow != value)
           {
               _currentDateTimeNow = value;
               RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentDateTimeNow");
           }
       }
   }
   //event
   private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
       if (PropertyChanged != null)
       {
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }
   }
   }
   }
   ```
2. In XAML add code for reflecting (mainPage.xaml)

   ```
   TextBlock x:Name="currentTime" FontSize="25" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" Margin="20,10,0,0"
                  Text="{Binding Path=CurrentDateTimeNow}"
   ```
3. After add some code (mainPage.xaml.cs)

   ```
   public MainPage()
   {
       this.InitializeComponent();
       this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
       this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
       this.navigationHelper.SaveState += navigationHelper_SaveState;

       //add binding to main page
       //currentTime.DataContext = DateTime.Now;

       //initialize instances
       _dateTimeNow = new DateTimeNow();
       //get current time
       _dateTimeNow.CurrentDateTimeNow = DateTime.Now.ToString();
       //register event
       _dateTimeNow.PropertyChanged += _dateTimeNow_PropertyChanged;
       //move data to text block
       ShowCurrentTime(currentTime);
   }

   //move information from prop to the text block
   private void ShowCurrentTime(TextBlock textBlock)
   {
       textBlock.Text = _dateTimeNow.CurrentDateTimeNow;
   }

   //do on changes time
   void _dateTimeNow_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       ShowCurrentTime(currentTime);
   }
   ```

As result got thet time reflected only for current moment - moment of launchning programm:

[image]

But every second nothing happend - time do not updated. Guess it's because i do not add some code for updating property every second - if property changed - my textBox information will be updated.

Question - how can i code, that property can be changed every second according to time changing? So why i ask - cant find `Timer` in windows store app. Maybe ther is another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer):

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ...

    var dateTimeNow = new DateTimeNow();
    DataContext = dateTimeNow;

    var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
    timer.Tick += (o, e) => dateTimeNow.CurrentDateTimeNow = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    timer.Start();
}
```

Note also that there is no need for your `_dateTimeNow_PropertyChanged` handler, because the TextBlock is already updated by the `CurrentDateTimeNow` Binding, provided that you have set the MainPage's `DataContext` to a DateTimeNow instance.

Comment: thanks, as i understand instead of timer in windows store app we can use DispatcherTimer. Also try to remove `_dateTimeNow_PropertyChanged` - result - time is not updating, so guess it's required. Any way thanks for help

Comment: @Kirill The property change handler is not required, definitely. Otherwise you did not need to have a binding at all. Just take care for setting the DataContext properly (or set the binding Source property explicitly).

Comment: try as you sad `currentTime.DataContext = _dateTimeNow.CurrentDateTimeNow;`but no changes at textBlock without event, maybe i make somewhere mistake

Comment: I didn't say that. You have to set the MainPage's DataContext, as shown in my answer: `DataContext = _dateTimeNow;`.